# dynamically adding images using for loop -objective c

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsstring

I am using below code to add number of images in a single cell content view.

```
    cell.imageView1.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"testImg1"];
            cell.imageView2.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"testImg2"];
            cell.imageView3.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"testImg3"];
            cell.imageView4.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"testImg4"];
            cell.imageView5.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"testImg5"];  
.............................  
............................  
cell.imageView20.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"testImg20"];
```

How to use for loop with stringWithFormat to make my code look conscise something like:

```
for(imageCounter = 1; imageCounter <21, imageCounter++)  
{  
cell.imageView(imageCounter).image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"testImg(imageCounter)"];  
}
```

Any Suggestion?

Comment: is all 20 imageview are in  same cell???

Comment: yes all 20 imageview(very small) are in same cell.I have subclassed UITableViewCell and made custom cell in my viewcontroller.

Comment: I put answer plz check and let me know if any clarification you need

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To reach references of the different image views inside the loop you have to either out them in an array or tag them than you can either go:

```
  NSArray *cellImageViews;
  for(int imageCounter = 1; imageCounter < 21; imageCounter++)
  {
    [[cellImageViews objectAtIndex:imageCounter-1] setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"testImg%d", imageCounter]]];
  }
```

or

```
  for(int imageCounter = 1; imageCounter <21; imageCounter++)
  {
    [((UIImageView *)[cell viewWithTag:imageCounter]) setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"testImg%d", imageCounter]]];
  }
```

Comment: hey both the way are working but second solution is just gawjus

Answer (score 1):

```
UIImageView *img[20];//ur array of images

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

for (int i=0; i<20; i++) {

        //set frame  every time as ur requirement

        img[i].image = [UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"testImg%d",i+1]];
        [cell.contentView addSubview:img[i]];
    }
}
```

I think this code work perfectly
[For More Examples](http://www.appsfor2012.com/2012/07/iphone-questions.html) for better Description.

Answer (score 1):

You are using wrong logic.It cannot be use like this.Instead of this

```
for(imageCounter = 1; imageCounter <21, imageCounter++)
{
 cell.imageView(imageCounter).image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"testImg%d,(imageCounter)"];
}
```

You should use this :-

```
yourImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(x, y, width, height)];

for(imageCounter = 1; imageCounter <21, imageCounter++)
{
 [yourImageView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"testImg%d",imageCounter]];
 cell.imageView = yourImageView;
}
```

Try this.Hope it gonna help you thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Hi you should first put all images in an array in  cellForRowAtIndexPath method

```
NSMutableArray *imageArr=[[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObject:cell.imageView1,cell.imageView2.....];
```

Then do the following:

```
for(imageCounter = 1; imageCounter <21, imageCounter++) {



[imageArr objectAtindex:imageCounter].image = [UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringwithformat:@"testImg%d", imageCounter]];
}
```

let me know if any clarification you need

Comment: Appreciating your help.i am not able to access .image property here :[imageArr objectAtindex:imageCounter].image.However with set image as in above solution its working yee :)